# Java garbage collection mechanism

Tags: java

When we write like this:
    {
    new A().test();
    }
The memory of A will be collected by gc after this function return(I knew that it's possible for collection, not be collected right now). The question is, how does the jvm make sure the memory of A won't be realise during the test() excuting(I assume the gc is a independent thread). I thought the compiler may change the statement into this:

```
{
    //cover it in a scope
    {
    A temp = new A();
    temp.test();
    }
    //outside the scope, temp is no longer stay in stack, so that A's memory can be colllected
}
```

This is just a conjecture.
BTW, very sorry for my poor English, please use simple syntax(to answer or explain), thanks.

Comment: @mre: the references don't have to be null -- GC occurs when an object (or even an object graph) becomes _unreachable_.

Comment: @Glenn That statement is 100% incorrect. There is no telling when or even whether the object will be garbage collected, and the prerequisite isn't null references, it is unreachability.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler generates byte code that ensures there is a temporary reference to the A on the stack, somewhat like your example.

Answer (score 0):

The gc checks for reachability of objects. Your object is allocated on the heap and a reference to it is placed on the stack of the current method being executed, which makes it reachable by the gc, so it won't be collected.

When your method returns that stack memory is not "reachable" anymore, so that single reference to the object in the heap is gone, so the gc is free to mark it for collection.

Your "temp" variable is just a pretty name for that reference that the compiler creates anyway.